# uWSGI: disable logs for given urls

Tags: logging, config, uwsgi

I need to disable uWSGI logs just for one url. I played around uWSGI config but didn't find anything that can helps(maybe route directive, but it didn't give me required result). 
Do you have any ideas about it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use its [internal routing framework](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/InternalRouting.html) with the `donotlog` action:

```
route = ^foo donotlog:
```

But ensure your instance has internal routing support compiled in (if not you should see a warning in the startup logs).

Comment: just a comment - to enable internal routing install `libpcre3, libpcre3-dev` and reinstall `uwsgi`. If not enabled you would see warning `!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!`